# succes method keeps showing up undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My cloud log says that it cannot call the method "success" of undefined at query.first.success
   however i dont understand this because my console.log is showing up which is called inside of the success block.  What is undefined in this code?

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Messages");
  query.first({
    success: function(results, response){

      console.log("The first object was retrieved");
      body = (results.get("messageBody"));
      senderName = (results.get("senderName"));
      senderId = (results.get("senderId"));

      results.destroy({
        success: function(results){

        }, error: function(results, error){

        }
      });
      response.success(results);
    }, error: function(error){
      response.error("Error");
    }

  });
```

Comment: Well, where is `response` defined?

Comment: okay. i edited my question showing where i added response but its still showing up as the same error

Comment: I don't think a [Query](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries) does give you access to a `response` object. You're setting up a [cloud function](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions), aren't you?

Comment: yes this snippet is inside of an afterSave function

Comment: Hm, it seems that afterX functions do not have access to the `response` object…